# Remove Punctuation and Spaces from string using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, encryption

I am trying to take out all the punctuation and spaces in a string that I am going to encrypt using a Playfair Cipher. I can't figure out why this line doesn't work.

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\w\s]", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `[^\w\s]` means remove anything that's not a word or whitespace character.

Try this instead:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\w]", string.Empty);
```

You could also use:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\W", string.Empty);
```

Of course that will leave underscores as those are considered word characters. To remove those as well, try this:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[\W_]", string.Empty);
```

Or this:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\W|_", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 4):

How about using Linq instead of Regex?

```
string str = "abc; .d";
var newstr = String.Join("", str.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `^` character means not. I use `[^A-Za-z0-9-]` for my replacements of everything not alpha-numeric with a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use `[^A-Za-z]` since `\w` contains `_` and `0-9` which I'm guessing you wouldn't want to keep.

The following regex would remove anything not `a-z` or `A-Z`.

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^A-Za-z]", string.Empty);
```